# Add Function to Existing Angular Controller in VirtoCommerce Storefront

Tags: virtocommerce

I would like to add a function to the cartController (angular) in the storefront.

I could fork the storefront and then make my change and start loading only "my" storefront.

Is there a way to build my own module with the purpose of extending or overriding the controller so I can still use the base storefront module and just extend with my changes.

Answer (score 0):

To extending storefront you should adhere to the following rules to be able to update to the latest storefront version without **'merging hell'**:

- Try to avoid direct exist storefront controller changes, create own
  controllers in separated solution folders with using prefixes for class and file names. e.g

> VirtoCommerce.Storefront/MyExtension/myCartController

- Register new routes and dependencies by modifying **Startup.cs** (it
  is exception)
- All storefront model classes marked as **partial** and will be easily
  to split the definition over two or more source files within
  **VirtoCommerce.Model** and **VirtoCommerce.LiquidThemeEngine** projects. e.g

> VirtoCommerce.Storefront.Model/MyExtension/ShoppingCart.cs

- About theme customization please read my answer on [Starting VirtoCommerce Storefront Theme Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443169/starting-virtocommerce-storefront-theme-development) stackoverflow question
- How to use new modules API in the storefront described in this article [How to generate module API C# client using AutoRest](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/development-scenarios/how-to-generate-module-api-c-sharp-client-using-autorest)

In this [article](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/development-scenarios/developing-a-custom-solution) you can see the overall solution development process.

Comment: So I'm specifically talking about the Angular controller in this case. I added a function and checked it in. I then rebased my fork with latest to ensure my changes sit on top to enforce the idea that base changes occur first and I build on top of those always. This worked this time but is there a better way to add a function to an Angular controller?

Comment: If you decided  to modify default theme '~/App_Data/Themes/default' you can edit everything there, but you should be aware on merging for not lose your changes, because default theme also can be modified in original repository. I would suggest for you create you own theme as copy of default and place it in own Github repository and make all the changes there.

Comment: The Angular controller is not in the theme it's in the storefront. I have my theme in my own repo as I explained in the answer to the theme question. That is working great. Are you saying I could place the controller in my theme and override there?

Comment: Ah I see the theme does have it. Easy enough. but the question should be updated to reflect that this is a theme issue only.